# Oracle 11g Creating a custom event trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, server-error

how to Create a Database event trigger called as AuditErr that will fire every time a server error occurs. The 
error refers to any Oracle error. This trigger can serve as a notification mechanism to an 
administrator, by populating an error log table, called server_error_log (use the given SQL script).
You should create the error lag table before-hand and when an error happens, the error code and 
details must be written back to this table.

CREATE TABLE server_error_log
(
    error_code decimal(6),
    description varchar2(256)
);

Comment: Looks suspiciously like homework :)

Comment: yeah its my assignment ;) lol thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a [database event trigger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#i2153530):

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER log_errors AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE 
>    BEGIN
>       // log error
>    END;
> ```

In this trigger, you can use the attribute functions [`ora_server_error`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#CHDHFBBG) and [`ora_server_error_msg`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#CHDCFDJG) to retrieve the error stack.

Comment: what do they mean by saying every time a server error occurs ? but by default oracle doesnt record all errors rite ? plzz explain